# Display div in correct place on desktop and mobile / accordion / move div?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, accordion

I have a page using bootstrap 4 which shows images of our team and uses accordion to reveal bios when you click the image.

On desktop it works fine, there are four images of people in a row. The bio is revealed below them when you click a profile.

However, on mobile, the view changes to four vertically stacked people images. When you click a person, the bio appears at the bottom, after the fourth person.

I want the bio to appear under the person you click.

Example image: 
[image: desired layout]

Code Example:

```
<section class="p-5">
<div class="container" id="biolevelone">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
       <div data-toggle="collapse" href="#bio1"><img src="image1.png"/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
       <div data-toggle="collapse" href="#bio2"><img src="image2.png"/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
       <div data-toggle="collapse" href="#bio3"><img src="image3.png"/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
       <div data-toggle="collapse" href="#bio4"><img src="image4.png"/></div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- row -->

<div class="collapse pt-2" id="bio1" data-parent="#biolevelone">
   <div class="card-body">
     <p>Bio text, a couple of paragraphs</p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="collapse pt-2" id="bio2" data-parent="#biolevelone">
   <div class="card-body">
     <p>Bio text, a couple of paragraphs</p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="collapse pt-2" id="bio3" data-parent="#biolevelone">
   <div class="card-body">
     <p>Bio text, a couple of paragraphs</p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="collapse pt-2" id="bio4" data-parent="#biolevelone">
   <div class="card-body">
     <p>Bio text, a couple of paragraphs</p>
   </div>
</div>

</div><!--biolevelone data parent -->
</section>
```

I tried moving the bio text cards code up between each profile image div, but then I get the opposite problem. i.e. On desktop, all the profile images suddenly vanish from the row and move below the bio text when an image is clicked, while working fine on mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanna ask if it is possible to add classes on your div, and if so please take a look on what I have done.

A little explanation though, just move your div that wraps the biography to every after the div that wraps the image. Then I just add class so that I can manipulate the div. Then add media query to show the biographies.

Anyway, just take a look below:

```css
.bio-container {
  position: relative; 
}
.biography {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 812px) {
    .biography {
        position: static;
    }
    .collapse {
        display: block !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section class="p-5">
<div class="container" id="biolevelone">
<div class="row bio-container">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
       <div data-toggle="collapse" href="#bio1"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/ffffff"/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse pt-2 biography" id="bio1" data-parent="#biolevelone">
       <div class="card-body">
         <p>Bio text, a couple of paragraphs 1</p>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
       <div data-toggle="collapse" href="#bio2"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/ffffff"/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse pt-2 biography" id="bio2" data-parent="#biolevelone">
       <div class="card-body">
         <p>Bio text, a couple of paragraphs 2</p>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
       <div data-toggle="collapse" href="#bio3"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/ffffff"/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse pt-2 biography" id="bio3" data-parent="#biolevelone">
       <div class="card-body">
         <p>Bio text, a couple of paragraphs 3</p>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
       <div data-toggle="collapse" href="#bio4"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/ffffff"/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse pt-2 biography" id="bio4" data-parent="#biolevelone">
       <div class="card-body">
         <p>Bio text, a couple of paragraphs 4</p>
       </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- row -->





</div><!--biolevelone data parent -->
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this. Works perfectly on mobile, and is an improvement on desktop. The only issue now is that on desktop the bio doesn't expand the available space to make room for itself. So the bio ends up overlapping the four images and the footer. Before the modification it had an accordion effect where it pushes footer down to create room. Any ideas?

Comment: First, sorry for the very late reply. Anyway, notice that I add .bio-container to the class "row". I added position: relative; so that the biographies relies on it. So basically, since I positioned absolute the biographies, it floats inside the "row" class. Maybe add some height to the "row" and instead of top: 200px;, just make the biographies bottom: 0;. Please take a look on this codepen I have made for you: https://codepen.io/jcarizon/pen/povmmWK

Comment: Thanks! As I eventually plan to have additional rows of bios, I stuck with your first solution. I had to remove the .collapse {display: block !important; } because it was making the bios unable to be hidden/collapsed.

Comment: For anyone else, I also tried another method: duplicating the entire bio section and giving one a 'desktop' class and one a 'mobile' class. Then just set display to  none or block depending on the screen size. This allowed me to keep the accordion effect on both screen types, but got a bit messy in terms of volume of code so I canned it.